# Powershell draw visio container

Tags: powershell, visio

I need to use powershell to draw visio, but I dont know how powershell can draw containers.

This is the article 
https://powershellstation.com/2016/04/18/powershell-and-visio-part-6-containers/

that I have referenced and followed, but it seems $master has not been declared somewhere so it is failing.

I wonder if anyone has any instructions for this problem.

This is my code

```
$Visio=New-Object -ComObject Visio.Application  
$doc=$Visio.Documents.Add(‘’)  
$Page=$Visio.ActivePage  
$stencilPath=$Visio.GetBuiltInStencilFile(2,0)
$stencil=$Visio.Documents.OpenEx($stencilPath,64)
$page=$Visio.ActivePage
$container=$page.Drop($master,5,5)
$rec=$page.DrawRectangle(2,3,5,6)
$container.ContainerProperties.AddMember($rec,1)
```

This is the error

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:7 char:1
+ $container.ContainerProperties.AddMember($rec,1)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: Did you look at Part 3 where I talked about drawing shapes?  https://powershellstation.com/2016/03/10/powershell-and-visio-part-3-drawing-shapes/

Comment: ```$Master=$stencil.Masters('FTP Server')
$Page.Drop($Master,4,4)
``` this command will select what shapes will be use in stencil right? but to draw container which masters i should select in BuiltInStencil. I'm not clear that point .So good when I can contact with you here. Thank for you respone.

Comment: I got it, that master is container style name. Just select classic and it work as i want. Thank you again!!! Can you explan more about add Selection objects to add multi object to container? @MikeShepard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code to draw container

```
$stencilPath=$viso.GetBuiltInStencilFile(2,0)
$stencil=$viso.Documents.OpenEx($stencilPath,64)
$Master=$stencil.Masters('Classic')
$Page.Drop($Master,11)
```